# How i can work with dict values in function signature

Tags: python

I have some list with dict inside

```
list_of_dict = [
    {'row_n': 1, 'nomenclature_name': 'some_nomenclature_name', 'article': '', 'TM': ''}, 
    {'row_n': 2, 'no_category': '', 'nomenclature_name': 'some_nomenclature_name', 'article': '', 'TM': ''}
]
```

Adn i translate this list_of_dict in the set.

```
uniq_nomenclature_names_from_imported_file = {value['nomenclature_name'] for value in list_of_dict if value['nomenclature_name'] != ''}
```

Because this logic can be reusable, i want make some method and just
redefine it. So, my question is, how i can work with dict values in function signature, for example:

```
def some_reusable_func(list_of_dict, dict_value):
        return uniq_nomenclature_names_from_imported_file = {value['dict_value'] for value in list_of_dict if value['dict_value'] != ''}


def my_case_with_list_of_dict():
    some_reusable_func(
        list_of_dict = some_list_of_dict,
        dict_value = 'some_dict_value'
)
```

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Note that this a "key", not a "value" we're talking about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access using the `dict_value` variable as a key directly instead of using the string `'dict_value'` in the comprehension (and return just the `set`, without `=` which would raise a `SyntaxError`):

```
def some_reusable_func(list_of_dict, dict_value):
        return {value[dict_value] for value in list_of_dict if value[dict_value] != ''}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def some_reusable_func(list_of_dict, k):
    return {i[k] for i in list_of_dict if i[k] != ''}
```

The assignment is a statement, not an expression, you can't return the value of an assignment or it would lead the error `invalid syntax`

Test

```
print(some_reusable_func(list_of_dict, 'nomenclature_name'))
# {'some_nomenclature_name'}
```

---

Or you can use lambda function.

```
some_reusable_func = lambda list_of_dict, k: {i[k] for i in list_of_dict if i[k] != ''}
some_reusable_func(list_of_dict, 'nomenclature_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun I tried creating a subclass of list and adding the function as a method to it.

```
class my_list(list):
    def get_names(self, name):
        return {value[name] for value in self if value.get(name) and value[name] != ''} 

list_of_dict = my_list([
    {'row_n': 1, 'nomenclature_name': 'some_nomenclature_name', 'article': '', 'TM': ''}, 
    {'row_n': 2, 'no_category': '', 'nomenclature_name': 'some_nomenclature_name', 'article': '', 'TM': ''},
])

print(list_of_dict.get_names('nomenclature_name'))
```

Result

```
{'some_nomenclature_name'}
```